# Replace conditional operator with if/else automatically?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, conditional-operator

A specific JS parser (not in my control) does not understand nested conditional operator syntax like this:

```
return num === 1 ? condition ? condition : something : something;
```

Hence, I would like to **replace all conditional operators (simple and nested) in a file with if/else blocks**. How do I go about it? (A regexp for Textmate or similar would be helpful.)

Comment: It so is valid (try `1 ? 2 ? 3 : 4 : 5`), but the `return`s in the subexpressions look suspect (try `1 ? 2 ? 3 : return 4 : return 5`).

Comment: @chris Fair enough, was just experimenting with it -- I wasn't sure. As for the `return`s, I assume he basically meant 'yield' as the value of the exp. Still, easier to bracket the inner expression than change completely to `if`/`else`

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young, Sorry, the returns in the subexpressions were not meant to be there. The question is only about replacing the conditional operator expressions with if/else. The code is valid JS.

Answer (score 5):

> How do I go about it? (A regexp for Textmate or similar would be helpful.

I don't think this is possible with regular expressions - you would need to parse the whole JS expression grammar with them. Of course you might use them to find appearances of ternary operators, but replacing them would need to be done by hand.

This is because conditional operators form expressions, while if/else structures are statements. That means you will need to lift the statement containing the ternary operator around the if-else. There are two solutions to transform the general

> *<some statement* ( *condition* `?` *then-expression* `:` *else-expression*) *>*

1. > `if (` *condition* `) {`
   >
   > *<some statement then-expression>*
   >
   > `} else {`
   >
   > *<some statement else-expression>*
   >
   > `}`
2. > `var helper;`
   >
   > `if (` *condition* `)`
   >
   > `helper =` *then-expression*`;`
   >
   > `else`
   >
   > `helper =` *else-expression*`;`
   >
   > *<some statement* `helper`*>*

Which of them to choose depends on the complexity of the *some statement* (for your `return`-statement I'd opt for #1). And since the replacements bring their own syntax rules, you even might need to adapt the surrounding blocks. All this is not a trivial task, and imho could be automated only if you already had a parsed AST to transform.

Answer (score 1):

One idea would be to transform `x ? y : z` into `(x && y) || z`. You're still probably going to have to do some fairly fancy parsing to find the ternary operators, but at least you can leave them as expressions rather than statements which will mean the changes needed are much less extensive. Note however that there might be cases where these two things are not exactly equivalent (e.g. if `y` is 0) so use this approach with caution and only when you have some control over what code it will be applied to.

The idea of `(x && y) || z` is that when x is truthy, it evaluates to y, and when x is falsey, it evaluates to z. This works due to some edge-cases in the way that JavaScript handles short-circuiting for non-Boolean values. It's sort of a generalization of standard boolean arithmetic. Essentially, JavaScript will return the last value that it needed to inspect in order to perform the operation. So `true && (stuff)` returns `stuff`, whereas `false && (stuff)` returns `false`. Likewise `true || (stuff)` returns `true`, whereas `false || (stuff)` returns `stuff`.

There are two cases to check to show that `(x && y) || z` (mostly) does what we want:

### Case 1: x is truthy

Since x is truthy, `(true && y) || z` evaluates to `y || z`. If y is also truthy, then this evaluates to y and we get our desired behavior. If y is not truthy, the operation fails and we get z instead!

### Case 2: x is falsey

Since x is falsey, `(false && y) || z` evaluates to `false || z`, which in turn evaluates to `z`. Here we are lucky and always get the desired behavior regardless of y.

### Example

Here's an example of the desired behavior in the chrome console:

```
> var x1 = "a" //truthy
> var x2 = "" //falsey
> var y = "y"
> var z = "z"
> (x1 && y) || z
"y"
> (x2 && y) || z
"z"
```

Just watch out for cases where `y` is not truthy!

```
> var y2 = 0
> (x1 && y2) || z
"z"
```

Comment: you mean `if(x){ return y;} else { return z;}` ?

Comment: @bowl0stu I'm not sure what you mean. That would be a statement rather than an expression, right? By sticking with short-circuiting Boolean operations you can keep it as an expression.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `(x && y) || z`. care to explain?

Comment: @bowl0stu Sure, I added an explanation to the answer, let me know if anything is unclear

Comment: thanks dude. never heard of short circuiting before; interesting concept

Answer (score 1):

For future researchers, I'd like to offer my solution approach for these cases where I want to improve conditional statements, either through the ternary operator, switch statements, or traditional if/if else/else statements.
It is already known by many that the use of an object literal for this purpose is a good practice, especially when you have several options and a given parameter that you can use to index this object. Give an example below.

**ternary operator version**

```
const getAnimalSpecies = (sound) =>
  sound === 'bark'
    ? 'Dogs'
    : sound === 'meow'
    ? 'Cats'
    : sound === 'howl'
    ? 'Wolfs'
    : 'Not animal found';
```

**switch statement version**

```
const getAnimalSpecies = (sound) => {
  switch (sound) {
    case 'bark':
      return 'Dogs'

    case 'meow':
      return 'Cats'

    case 'howl':
      return 'Wolfs'
    
    default:
      return 'Not animal found'
  }
}
```

**if/if else/else statement version**

```
const getAnimalSpecies = (sound) => {
  if (sound === 'bark') {
    return 'Dogs';
  } else if (sound === 'meow') {
    return 'Cats';
  } else if (sound === 'howl') {
    return 'Wolfs';
  } else {
    return 'Not animal found';
  }
};
```

**object literal version**

```
const getAnimalSpecies = (sound) => {
  const animalSounds = {
    bark: 'Dogs',
    meow: 'Cats',
    howl: 'Wolfs'
  }
  return animalSounds[sound] ?? 'Not animal found'
}
```

**All these statements return the same results!**

```
getAnimalSpecies('bark') // Dogs
getAnimalSpecies('purring') // Not animal found
```

But I think you can agree with me that the last one it's prettier and cleaner.

Beyond that, I found myself in a different situation, where the results were given by Booleans obtained by the parameter already processed. Sound complex ha !? Lets put two examples.

1. ***First one***

**ternary operator version**

```
const imageExtensionAtEnd = /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|tiff?|webp|bpm|jfif)$/i;
const pdfExtensionAtEnd = /\.(pdf)$/i;
const audioExtensionAtEnd = /\.(mp3|amr|aac)$/i;
const videoExtensionAtEnd = /\.(ogm|wmv|webm|ogv|mov|asx|m4v|mp4|avi|3gp|mkv|mpe?g)$/i;

const getFileType = (file) => {
  const type = imageExtensionAtEnd.test(file)
    ? 'image'
    : videoExtensionAtEnd.test(file)
    ? 'video'
    : pdfExtensionAtEnd.test(file)
    ? 'application'
    : audioExtensionAtEnd.test(file)
    ? 'audio'
    : undefined;
  return type;
};
```

**object literal version**

```
export const getFileType = (file) => {
  const fileTypes = {
    [imageExtensionAtEnd.test(file)]: 'image',
    [videoExtensionAtEnd.test(file)]: 'video',
    [pdfExtensionAtEnd.test(file)]: 'application',
    [audioExtensionAtEnd.test(file)]: 'audio'
  };

  return fileTypes['true'] ?? undefined;
};
```

2. Second one

**conditional version**

```
import { useMediaQuery } from '@material-ui/core';

const defaulValues = ['', '', '', '', ''];

const useMediaVariant = (values = defaulValues) => {
  const [xs, sm, md, lg, xl] = values;

  if (useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)')) {
    return xs;
  }
  if (useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)')) {
    return sm;
  }
  if (useMediaQuery('(min-width:960px)')) {
    return md;
  }
  if (useMediaQuery('(min-width:1280px)')) {
    return lg;
  }
  if (useMediaQuery('(min-width:1920px)')) {
    return xl;
  } else {
    return values.at(-1);
  }
};
```

**object literal version**

```
const useMediaVariant = (values = defaulValues) => {
  const [xs, sm, md, lg, xl] = values;

  const variant = {
    [useMediaQuery('(max-width:600px)')]: xs,
    [useMediaQuery('(min-width:600px)')]: sm,
    [useMediaQuery('(min-width:960px)')]: md,
    [useMediaQuery('(min-width:1280px)')]: lg,
    [useMediaQuery('(min-width:1920px)')]: xl
  };

  return variant['true'] || values.at(-1);
};

export default useMediaVariant;
```

It is used liked this example:

```
import useMediaVariant from '.../hooks/useMediaVariant';

const valueHeading = useMediaVariant(['subtitle2', 'h8'])

<Typography variant={valueHeading} />
```

The second one is a custom hook I create to apply responsiveness in some material-ui components props...

> Note that when you use the `object['true']` method the last occurrence found will be the one returned. *Important thing if there is more than one truthy possibility.*

***Hope to help someone.***