# Replace nested conditional operators with if/else in this block

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

What would this block look like using if/else statements instead of the ternary?

> return value == null ? name.local ? attrNullNS : attrNull : typeof
>   value === "function" ? name.local ? attrFunctionNS : attrFunction :
>   name.local ? attrConstantNS : attrConstant;

(I want to be certain that I do this right before tackling another 15 similar blocks ... Ideally I'd like to replace all such blocks with a regexp, but there seems to be no method?    [Replace conditional operator with if/else automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690067/replace-conditional-operator-with-if-else-automatically))

Answer (score 2):

Good question.

First of all, I agree that the developer who left you with this code should be LARTed.

However, you can figure this out (without code formatters such as in [Eclipse JSDT](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jsdt/)) if you consider that [the syntax for the Conditional Operator is `LogicalORExpression ? AssignmentExpression : AssignmentExpression` or `… : AssignmentExpressionNoIn`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12) and that [the *longest* possible match wins](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7).

Adjacent expressions that belong to the same atomic conditional operation cannot be delimited by either `?`s or `:`s on *both* sides because the grammar does not allow that.  So just put yourself into the position of a LL(n) parser that works according to the ECMAScript grammar ;-)  Repeatedly ask yourself the question “Can this code be produced by the production for that goal symbol?”; if the answer is “no”, backtrack to the shorter match until it can, or fail with a syntax error if no production works.

1. `return` **`(`**`value == null ? name.local ? attrNullNS : attrNull : typeof value === "function" ? name.local ? attrFunctionNS : attrFunction : name.local ? attrConstantNS : attrConstant`**`)`**`;`
2. `return (value == null ?` **`(`**`name.local ? attrNullNS : attrNull` **`)`** `:` **`(`**`typeof value === "function" ? name.local ? attrFunctionNS : attrFunction : name.local ? attrConstantNS : attrConstant`**`)`**`);`
3. `return (`**`(`**`value == null`**`)`** `? (name.local ? attrNullNS : attrNull) : (` **`(`**`typeof value === "function"`**`)`** `?` **`(`**`name.local ? attrFunctionNS : attrFunction`**`)`** `:` **`(`**`name.local ? attrConstantNS : attrConstant`**`)`**`));`

And so:

```
if (value == null)
{
  if (name.local)
  {
    return attrNullNS;
  }
  else
  {
    return attrNull;
  }
}
else
{
  if (typeof value === "function")
  {
    if (name.local)
    {
      return attrFunctionNS;
    }
    else
    {
      return attrFunction;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    if (name.local)
    {
      return attrConstantNS;
    }
    else
    {
      return attrConstant;
    }
  }
}
```

(CMIIW.)  This can be further reduced to

```
if (value == null)
{
  if (name.local)
  {
    return attrNullNS;
  }

  return attrNull;
}

if (typeof value === "function")
{
  if (name.local)
  {
    return attrFunctionNS;
  }

  return attrFunction;
}

if (name.local)
{
  return attrConstantNS;
}

return attrConstant;
```

Answer (score 0):

Did this really fast by just replacing the ternary operators, but I'm guessing it would look a lot like this:

```
if (value == null) {
    if (name.local) {
        return attrNullNS;
    }else{
        return attrNull;
    }
}else if (typeof value === "function") {
    if (name.local) {
        return attrFunctionNS;
    }else{
        return attrFunction;
    }
}else{
    if (name.local) {
        return attrConstantNS;
    }else{
        return attrConstant;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax ("grouping") of ternary operators and blockless if-else-statements are quite similar, so you could start by replacing each `… ?` with `if (…)` and each `:` with `else`. Then wrap the `return` statement around each, and use auto-indentation. Maybe you can even do some of these tasks carefully (step-by-step) with an auto-replace. You'll end up with

```
if (value == null)
    if (name.local) 
        return attrNullNS;
    else
        return attrNull;
else if (typeof value === "function")
    if (name.local)
        return attrFunctionNS;
    else
        return attrFunction;
else if (name.local)
    return attrConstantNS;
else
    return attrConstant;
```

Comment: Hopefully they will end up with something that contains braces.

Comment: @PointedEars: If you think they improve readability, your auto-indentation should be able to add them. I omitted them on purpose to show my point that braceless conditional statements are very like braceless ternary operators.

Comment: What are you talking about? Auto-indentation alone *cannot* automatically add braces. More important than readability is maintainability. This code will start to fail the moment there is not only one statement dependent on the conditional expression.

Comment: @PointedEars: OK, not the indentation alone but the tidy-up/pretty-print/whatever feature of your editor. And of course there is only one statement allowed in a if-else, but since the original ternary operator has the same limitation this is not a problem here - for the conversion. If you need to modify the code later braces might be useful, that's clear.